# C# - How to break from a loop if the function that triggered it is called again?

Tags: c#, string, loops, unity-game-engine, foreach

I'm developing a video game with C# and Unity, and my TypeDialog IEnumerator function is meant to type out a string to a UI text box. This works, however when it gets called twice it will try to print out two strings at the same time.

So for example if I call the function and pass in the string "string 1", and seconds later call it again and pass in "string 2", the UI text box will show the messages as "ssttrriinngg 12". How can I change this code so that if it is called a second time, it will stop printing the first message?

```
    public IEnumerator TypeDialog(string dialog)
{
    dialogText.text = "";
    foreach (var letter in dialog.ToCharArray())
    {
        dialogText.text += letter;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f / letterPerSecond);
    }

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you just need to stop the previous coroutine.

When you call StartCoroutine() you can save the coroutine that it makes into a variable in your class, and then stop it later when you need to.

```
public class MyBehaviour : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] TextMeshProUGUI dialogText = default;
    [SerializeField] int lettersPerSecond = 15;
    Coroutine typeDialogRoutine = null;

    public void TypeDialog(string dialog)
    {
        if(typeDialogRoutine != null)
           StopCoroutine(typeDialogRoutine);
        typeDialogRoutine = StartCoroutine(DoTypeDialogRoutine(dialog));
    }

    IEnumerator DoTypeDialogRoutine(string dialog)
    {
        dialogText.text = "";
        foreach (var letter in dialog.ToCharArray())
        {
            dialogText.text += letter;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f / letterPerSecond);
        }

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
        typeDialogRoutine = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Cache `Coroutine` in private variable, then stop it before next dialog.

```cs
private Coroutine dialogCoroutine;
void NewDialouge(string _text)
{
    if (dialogCoroutine != null) StopCoroutine(dialogCoroutine); // this will stop currently dialog..
    dialogCoroutine = StartCoroutine(TypeDialog(_text));
}

IEnumerator TypeDialog(string dialog)
{
    ...
}
```